# Rearrange 2nd sequence so that no two elements at same index are equal.

Tags: algorithms, rearrangement-inequality

Given 2 sequences `a` and `b` what is best way to rearrange the `b` array so that no two elements at same index are equal.

Example

```
a = 1 1 1 2 2 3
b = 1 1 1 2 2 3
```

we can rearrange b to make `2 2 3 1 1 1` and hence no two elements at same index are same.

Note

It can be possible that there is no rearrangement as well.
Assume 1st sequence is sorted

Comment: What's the best way you found?

Answer (score 0):

This is the matching (or marriage) problem, where „boy“ $i$ and „girl“ $j$ can match iff $a_i\ne b_j$.